# Export Office Excel table to csv using a macro

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, csv

I'm using Excel Tables in Excel 2010.  I would like to quickly export the contents of these tables to *.csv.

My current workflow:
1. Select table manually
2. Copy the contents into a new workbook
3. Save the workbook as a *.csv file

Desired workflow:
1. Select table manually
2. Run a macro that writes to a pre-defined file name

Since the tables have unique names (e.g. CurrentDataTable), is there a function that takes the table name, target file, and desired output format and writes the output file?

Comment: Is there a fixed path for your output? Is there only one table per sheet?

Comment: There is a fixed path. Generally I would prefer not to be limited to one table per sheet (I would like to I'd tables by their names vs. the sheet they are on)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no built-in Excel command or function that would do the kind of thing you want, but you can use VBA to program it.

The following code may be close to what you are looking for:

```
Sub ExportTable()

    Dim wb As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim wbNewName As String


   Set wb = ThisWorkbook
   Set ws = ActiveSheet

   Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add

   With wbNew
       Set wsNew = wbNew.Sheets("Sheet1")
       wbNewName = ws.ListObjects(1).Name
       ws.ListObjects(1).Range.Copy
       wsNew.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
       .SaveAs Filename:=wb.Path & "\" & wbNewName & ".csv", _
             FileFormat:=xlCSVMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False
   End With

End Sub
```

The code assumes that you have one table in each worksheet. It creates a new workbook, copies the table into Sheet 1 of that workbook, and saves the workbook as a CSV file with the same name as the table.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my version of chuff's answer for Excel 2013. It also disables the modal dialogs:

```
Sub ExportCSV()

   Dim wb As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook
   Dim ws As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet

   Set wb = ThisWorkbook
   Set ws = ActiveSheet

   Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   With wbNew
       Set wsNew = wbNew.Sheets("Sheet1")
       ws.Rows.Copy
       wsNew.Paste
       .SaveAs Filename:=ws.name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True
       wsNew.Delete
   End With
   Windows(ws.name & ".csv").Activate
   ActiveWindow.Close
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do the same, but needed to specify which tables had to be exported as CSV files.  I created a range named 'ExportTables', with the VBA as follows:

```
Public Sub Export()
    Dim i       As Integer
    Dim iMax    As Integer
    Dim sTable  As String

    iMax = Range("ExportTables").Rows.Count

    For i = 1 To iMax
        sTable = Range("ExportTables").Cells(i, 1).Value
        Call ExportTable(sTable)
    Next i
End Sub

Public Sub ExportTable(tableName As String)
    Dim wkb         As Workbook
    Dim wkbNew      As Workbook
    Dim wks         As Worksheet
    Dim wksNew      As Worksheet

    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook

    Application.Goto Reference:=tableName
    Set wks = ActiveSheet

    Set wkbNew = Workbooks.Add
    Set wksNew = wkbNew.Sheets(1)

    wks.ListObjects(tableName).Range.Copy
    wksNew.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    wkbNew.SaveAs Filename:=wkb.Path & "\" & tableName & ".csv", _
        FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    wkbNew.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ' Release object variables.
    Set wkb = Nothing
    Set wkbNew = Nothing
    Set wks = Nothing
    Set wksNew = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a 1004 error from the code above .Delete in Thorsten's code.   I merged it with [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51987976/excel-vba-runtime-error-1004-when-deleting-sheet1) and got this, which works for me:

```
Sub ExportCSV2()

   Dim wb As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook
   Dim ws As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet

   Set wb = ThisWorkbook
   Set ws = ActiveSheet

   Application.DisplayAlerts = False

   ws.Copy
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ws.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True
   Windows(ws.Name & ".csv").Activate
   ActiveWorkbook.Close False
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Please note, this (Thorsten's) approach exports the whole sheet, not just the table, so you get a LOT of empty rows.